# How to delete row with 1:1 relation to the same table?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, cascade, one-to-one

I using Entity Framework Core, and I have a table:

```
public class BlogComment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public BlogPost Post { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(254)]
    public string AuthorEmail { get; set; }
    public bool SendMailOnReply { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2000)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public int? ReplyToId { get; set; }
    public BlogComment ReplyTo { get; set; }
}
```

From this, EFC generates the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment] (
    [Id]              INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AuthorEmail]     NVARCHAR (254)  NULL,
    [AuthorName]      NVARCHAR (100)  NULL,
    [Content]         NVARCHAR (2000) NULL,
    [CreatedTime]     DATETIME2 (7)   NOT NULL,
    [PostId]          INT             NULL,
    [ReplyToId]       INT             NULL,
    [SendMailOnReply] BIT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BlogComment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogComment_BlogPost_PostId] FOREIGN KEY ([PostId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BlogPost] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogComment_BlogComment_ReplyToId] FOREIGN KEY ([ReplyToId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BlogComment] ([Id])
);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BlogComment_PostId]
    ON [dbo].[BlogComment]([PostId] ASC);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_BlogComment_ReplyToId]
    ON [dbo].[BlogComment]([ReplyToId] ASC) WHERE ([ReplyToId] IS NOT NULL);
```

Some comments are send as a reply to another, but not all. When the original comment is deleted, the reply becomes a normal comment. So, following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete), the configuration looks is this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BlogComment>()
      .HasOne(p => p.ReplyTo)
      .WithOne()
      .HasForeignKey<BlogComment>(c => c.ReplyToId)
      .IsRequired(false)
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

The delete method is pretty simple:

```
var comment = await context.BlogComment.Include(c => c.ReplyTo).SingleAsync(m => m.Id == id);
context.BlogComment.Remove(comment);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But I can't run it, I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_BlogComment_BlogComment_ReplyToId".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove `.Include(c => c.ReplyTo)` from your code

Comment: @viveknuna At first I didn't include it, and now I removed, but I get the same error.

Comment: can you check if ReplyToId is nullable in database table?

Comment: @viveknuna Yes, it is. I added the table's code to the question. The table has several comments right now that is not a reply to another ie `ReplyToId` is null.

Comment: Sorry, then I have no idea. Maybe you can give a try to `comment.ReplyTo = null;` before save changes.

Comment: When I try this (using the current stable EF core version 2.0.3) I get the infamous exception that the FK causes cycles or multiple cascade paths. That's a SQL Server restriction you can't evade. Which EF version do you have? It seems that the implementation has changed in the mean time.

Comment: @GertArnold 2.0.3 too, but I have `options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. I can't even create the table.

Comment: By the way, the relationship should be 1:n: `WithMany` instead of `WithOne`. Still can't create the table then though. I'm surprised you don't have this problem.

Comment: Ohhhh. Thanks, you're right, a comment can have more replies... It was worth to post this question. :D I had that cyclic error too, but I could solve this somehow at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap up the conversation in the comments:

First, the self reference is a 1:n association:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BlogComment>()
      .HasOne(p => p.ReplyTo)
      .WithMany(c => c.Replies)
      .HasForeignKey(c => c.ReplyToId)
      .IsRequired(false)
      .OnDelete(<we'll get to that>);
```

So, just for convenience, `BlogComment` now also has a property

```
public ICollection<BlogComment> Replies { get; set; }
```

However, I can't create the table using

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

It gives me

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_BlogComments_BlogComments_ReplyToId' on table 'BlogComments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

This is a Sql Server restriction we just have to accept, no way to evade it. The only way to get the desired cascade behavior is

```
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
```

[Which is](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.deletebehavior?view=efcore-2.0):

> For entities being tracked by the DbContext, the values of foreign key properties in dependent entities are set to null. This helps keep the graph of entities in a consistent state while they are being tracked, such that a fully consistent graph can then be written to the database. (...) This is the default for optional relationships.

I.e.: the client executes SQL to nullify the foreign key values. The child records should be tracked though. To remove a `BlogComment` parent the delete action should look like:

```
using (var db = new MyContext(connectionString))
{
    var c1 = db.BlogComments
        .Include(c => c.Replies) // Children should be included
        .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
    db.BlogComments.Remove(c1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you see, you don't have to set `ReplyToId = null`, that's something EF takes care of.

Comment: This is, however, not 1:1, you may describe that case too regarding to the original question. Though it will be useful for me, thanks.

Comment: The 1:0..1 case isn't really different in EF-core. The table structure can be identical (i.e. a separate foreign key, not a shared primary key relationship as EF6 stipulated).  The same cascade restriction apply and both parent and child should be tracked to make `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull` work.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. The only difference with one-to-one is the unique constraint in the later case. But the essential part is the `ClientSetNull` and the inverse navigation property. In the case of one-to-one, replace `Replies` with `public BlogComment Reply { get; set; }`, `WithOne(c => c.Reply)` and `Include(c -> c.Reply)`

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to `Include()` the entities I needed to be "dealt with" when I deleted an entity. EF cant manage things it is not currently tracking.

```
var breedToDelete = context.Breed
    .Include(x => x.Cats)
    .Single(x => x.Id == testBreedId);

context.Breed.Remove(breedToDelete);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get it working by manually setting `ReplyTo` to null. I'm still looking for a better solution, or an explanation why is it needed. Isn't it what `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)` supposed to do?

```
var comment = await context.BlogComment.Include(c => c.ReplyTo).SingleAsync(m => m.Id == id);
var reply = await context.BlogComment.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ReplyToId == id);
if (reply != null)
{
    reply.ReplyTo = null;
    reply.ReplyToId = null;
    context.Entry(reply).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
context.BlogComment.Remove(comment);
```